# create category and subcategory menu on the left sidebar

Tags: navigation

> I need a category, subcategory and subbactegory based solution for
>   example

```
Project
    Web project
        Project 1
        Project 2
    Desktop project
        Project 1
        Project 2
```

Project 1 (when i click this then content appear on right side)
Project 2 (when i click this then content appear on right side)

> Basically, when i click on the li page wouldn't be refresh. 1) i click
>   on web project then menu expanded Project 1, project 2 appear and if i
>   click on project 1 then content related to project 1 appear on the
>   right side. Similarly for Project 2 and the subcategory for desktop
>   project will be same means i can create subcategory related to desktop
>   project.. Like in any category and product relation we need to select
>   the category and add the product detail similarly in this

Answer (score 1):

- [Views Tree](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_tree) would be worth trying.
- Toggling of leaf terms can be handled by javascript.
- To show content, you can declare ajaxified menu callbacks, which simply takes tid as argument and replace a certain section of DOM with the server reponse.